# Android java json parse empty

Tags: javascript, android, json

> for json:

```
{
      "ayetler" : [
        {
          "ayet" : {
            "title" : "(1/96, Alak/1-5)",
            "body" : "Oluşturan; insanı embriyondan oluşturan Rabbinin adına öğren-öğret!\\n"
          }
        },
        {
          "ayet" : {
            "title" : "(1/96, Alak/15-19)",
            "body" : "O zaman o, meclisini/örgütünü çağırsın.\\n"
          }
    },
```

> and buffer class return jArray
>   JsonArraySend class

```
  JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
  jArray = object.getJSONArray("ayetler");
```

> in asyncTask :

```
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject row;

        row = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONPojo item = new JSONPojo();

        item.setTitle(row.getString("title").toString());
        item.setBody(row.getString("body").toString());

        meal_list.add(item);
    }
}
catch (JSONException e) {}
return meal_list;
```

but,listview empty 
why listview empty
Where am I doing wrong

Comment: If that's all your JSON, it has a syntax error.

Comment: http://meal.salatgah.com/alak.json no syntax error

Comment: It's probably throwing an exception, show us the message, System.out.println(e.getMessage);

Comment: can you put a break point and see if meal_list is not empty after "for" operation?

Comment: I suggest you use a library like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) for automatically parsing JSON into models. This is also more robust and you don’t have to write unnecessary code.

Comment: of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `"title"` and `"body"` Strings are under `"ayet"` node, not the `JSONArray` element.

Try like this:

```
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

        JSONObject row = obj.getJSONObject("ayet");

        JSONPojo item = new JSONPojo();
        item.setTitle(row.getString("title").toString());
        item.setBody(row.getString("body").toString());

        meal_list.add(item);
    }
}
catch (JSONException e) {}
return meal_list;
```